# Tomar "n" cantidad de dígitos de un campo fecha (Postgresql, SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Buenos días comunidad,

Actualmente necesito extraer una data de la base de datos, la misma debo agruparla por el mes y el año asociado a determinado registro, el tema es que el campo fecha se registró de esta manera por ejemplo: 2018-08-23 y necesito solamente el mes y el año, es decir como resultado 2018-08. Estuve tratando con el siguiente script:

```
SELECT datos, fecha,
   LEFT(fecha, 4) AS fechaarreglada
FROM tabla
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```html
ERROR:  no existe la función left(date, integer)
LINE 2:        LEFT(fechaenvio, 4) AS fechaarreglada
               ^
HINT:  Ninguna función coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversión explícita de tipos.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 35
```

Cualquier ayuda que me ayude a obtener el dato: 2018-08 es bienvenida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza en tu caso lo siguiente;

```
substring(fecha::text,1,7)
```

Convierte a texto la fecha y extrae la cantidad de caracteres que necesitas ver.

Quedaria asi;

```
SELECT datos, substring(fecha::text,1,7)
FROM tabla
```

Comment: Excelente, corrió hermoso, gracias.

Comment: urraaaa!, recuerda marcar como `respuesta aceptada`

Comment: Disculpa, existe la manera que ese resultado lo pueda utilizar en un select y group by a la vez?

Comment: si, seria `SELECT COUNT(datos), substring(fecha::text,1,7) AS fecha
FROM tabla
GROUP BY fecha` nota que he agregado un alias para agrupar